# How to store a json value in a variable when it was fetched with an api call (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, fetch-api

I am learning javascript and I was required to do a task that involves fetching a value from an API to use it for something else.

My problem here is that I don't know how to store the value fetched from the API that is a JSON object I believe in a variable, I have read documentation, and watched tutorials but nothing seems to be like my case or similar to help me.

I will provide the code, the output, and what I want.

My code (This API its a public one just for testing)

```
fetch('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data=> console.log(data))
```

My output (data inside is not real, just for test purpouses)

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "transaction": "testestest",
      "records": [
        {
          "CONO": "123",
          "WHLO": "555",
          "POPN": "123124124",
          "ITNO": "124124",
          "WHNM": "124 - 1124",
          "ITDS": "FILT 124124 142 GETZ 1,6LI",
          "STAT": "20",
          "QUQT": "0",
          "UNMS": "E12414A",
          "LEAT": "71241242",
          "LTDT": "124124",
          "RJQT": "0",
          "PFTM": "0",
          "PFDT": "142412",
          "STQT": "0",
          "RESP": "142",
          "ORQT": "0",
          "ACT1": "A1",
          "ACT2": "",
          "ACT3": "",
          "ACT4": "",
          "ACT5": "",
          "ACT6": "",
          "ACT7": "",
          "REQT": "0",
          "ALAR": "0",
          "AV02": "0",
          "PUIT": "2",
          "SSQT": "1",
          "AVAL": "0",
          "REOP": "0",
          "ALQT": "0",
          "ASOT": "0",
          "VTDT": "",
          "EOQT": "0",
          "AV01": "0",
          "ABCD": "1sadE",
          "STTX": "124124124",
          "STCW": "0",
          "RJCW": "0",
          "QUCW": "0",
          "CSTQ": "0",
          "CQUQ": "0",
          "CRJQ": "0",
          "CSTW": "0",
          "CQUW": "0",
          "CRJW": "0",
          "CHN2": "46"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "wasTerminated": false,
  "nrOfSuccessfullTransactions": 1,
  "nrOfFailedTransactions": 0
}
```

The question is what code will get me the field "AV01" stored in a variable?

Kind regards for everyone for the help.

Comment: `data.results[0].records[0].AV01`

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is key, but I also added a function to show results of the actual.
I added both your sample fake JSON as a string, parsed that and console log for that but also the actual as elements to a page as simple as possible; but all of them.

```js
//Assume you have this string (JSON is a string)
let JSONString = '{"results":[{"transaction":"testestest","records":[{"CONO":"123","WHLO":"555","POPN":"123124124","ITNO":"124124","WHNM":"124 - 1124","ITDS":"FILT 124124 142 GETZ 1,6LI","STAT":"20","QUQT":"0","UNMS":"E12414A","LEAT":"71241242","LTDT":"124124","RJQT":"0","PFTM":"0","PFDT":"142412","STQT":"0","RESP":"142","ORQT":"0","ACT1":"A1","ACT2":"","ACT3":"","ACT4":"","ACT5":"","ACT6":"","ACT7":"","REQT":"0","ALAR":"0","AV02":"0","PUIT":"2","SSQT":"1","AVAL":"0","REOP":"0","ALQT":"0","ASOT":"0","VTDT":"","EOQT":"0","AV01":"0","ABCD":"1sadE","STTX":"124124124","STCW":"0","RJCW":"0","QUCW":"0","CSTQ":"0","CQUQ":"0","CRJQ":"0","CSTW":"0","CQUW":"0","CRJW":"0","CHN2":"46"}]}],"wasTerminated":false,"nrOfSuccessfullTransactions":1,"nrOfFailedTransactions":0}';
console.log(JSONString);
//Pase the JSON
let obj = JSON.parse(JSONString);
//uncomment the console logs to follow the stack down.
// ALL THE PARSED:
//console.log(obj);
//the results
//console.log(obj.results);
//the results first property
//console.log(obj.results[0]);
//the results records
//console.log(obj.results[0].records);
//the results records array first object
//console.log(obj.results[0].records[0]);
console.log(obj.results[0].records[0].CONO);
console.log(obj.results[0].records[0].AV01);

// some code to process from the API
function processGoodStuff(goodstuff) {
  // console.log(goodstuff);
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  goodstuff.entries.some((entry, index, array) => {
    const tag = document.createElement("div");
    const text = document.createTextNode(index + ":"+entry.API);
    tag.appendChild(text);
    container.appendChild(tag);
    // just show 10 for simplicity)
    return index >= 9;
  });
}

fetch('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => processGoodStuff(data));
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

#container div {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```